# Android Application doPost

Tags: android, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest

I am having a problem doing a simple http post request from my android app to my Google Application.

So here is the error message:

```
07-16 15:58:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 15:58:02.314: E/AndroidRuntime(911): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not     execute method of the activity
```

It happens in my android app at the httpclient.execute command:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8888/mywebapp");
try {
// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
```

On my server there is no trace that I arrive in my post method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  ServletException, IOException {
System.out.println("SYL: POST request received");
super.doPost(req, resp);
}
```

The server is google webb app running under my eclipse locally with this conf:

```
<servlet-name>MyWebApp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.my.mywebapp.MyWebAppServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyWebApp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/mywebapp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If a test a get method that I call through a web navigator it works.
But calling the get in java (same way as I do for the post) does not work.
It like in the android app the connection can not be make with my server.

I put these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Can someone help me please??

Thank you.

PS:

Still the same error with replaceing localhost with 10.0.2.2.
I am copying the complete trace:

```
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     ... 11 more
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.my.my.MyActivity.sendMessage(MyActivity.java:72)
07-16 18:13:34.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: are you doing this on the UI-thread? you should post the entire exception

Comment: ok it was that!! I created a thread and it s working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are debugging in a local server, change the IP you want to access, and set this one: 10.0.2.2.
So, your httpost will look this way:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888/mywebapp");
```

For more info, http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: solved. thanks a lot (problem was both the address ad the fact i did not put the call in a thread)