# How to make http post from android to google app engine server?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, http

I am trying to make an http post request from my android to my server on GAE.

On the android side it seems like the post goes fine, but on the server side, doPost(...) never gets called.  Can anyone tell me why?

Here's my relevant android code:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(View... arg0)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://elf-security.appspot.com");
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://elf-security.appspot.com/gae_hellowordl");
//      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8888/gae_hellowordl");
        httpPost.addHeader("test", "Success!");

        Log.i(TAG, "Just about to send http request to " + httpPost.getURI());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.i(TAG, "Received http response..");

        Log.i(TAG, httpResponse.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And here's my relevant server code:

```
public class GAE_HelloWordlServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private Logger LOG;

    public GAE_HelloWordlServlet()
    {
        LOG = Logger.getLogger("GAE_HelloWordlServlet");
        LOG.info("GAE_HelloWordlServlet()");
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        LOG.info("doGet():  request test header:  " + req.getHeader("test"));
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        LOG.info("doPost():  request test header:  " + req.getHeader("test"));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GAE_HelloWordl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>gae.helloworld.GAE_HelloWordlServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GAE_HelloWordl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<!--        <url-pattern>/gae_hellowordl</url-pattern> -->
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: On the server side, are you running on dev_appserver? On the client side, are you running on emulator? if both yes, see if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508488/android-application-dopost) helps.

Comment: On the server side I'm just running locally from eclipse.  I'm not sure whether that's dev_appserver or not.  On the client side I'm running from my s3.

Comment: I tried it anyway (changing address for post to "http://10.0.2.2:8888/elf-security", and now the httpClient.execute(...) doesn't return).  I feel like the address is right, but maybe there's something wrong with my post request?

Comment: In this case (real device -> dev_appserver), first you need make your dev_appserver accessible on the network (start dev_appserver with argument --address=0.0.0.0, see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments)), then in your android app, change your code to point to the correct IP address, say if your desktop IP is 192.168.1.6, use `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.6:8888/gae_hellowordl");`.

Comment: Awesome, let me try that!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much!  That worked!!  When I deploy the server, do I guess I need to change the post address back to `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://elf-security.appspot.com/gae_hellowordl");`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check your web.xml and make sure the URL path is properly mapped to the servlet that handle it:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mysite.GAE_HelloWordlServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Check out dev guide [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#About_Deployment_Descriptors) for more details:

> ### Servlets and URL Paths
>
> web.xml defines mappings between URL paths and the servlets that handle requests with those paths. The web server uses this configuration to identify the servlet to handle a given request and call the class method that corresponds to the request method (e.g. the doGet() method for HTTP GET requests).
>
> ... ...

### Update:

- Case 1: Android emulator -> Appengine dev_server (both running on same machine):

  See this Q&A: [Android Application doPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508488/android-application-dopost)
- Case 2: Android real device -> Appengine dev_server (both on the same network):

  First make sure Appengine dev_appserver is accessible on the network (by starting dev_appserver with argument --address=0.0.0.0, see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments) for more details). Second in your android app, change your code to point to the correct IP address, say if your desktop IP is 192.168.1.6, use `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.6:8888/gae_hellowordl");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  But that doesn't seem to be the problem (I'll chuck my web.xml file just in case).  When I navigate to the site in a browser, the "doGet" method is called.  When I try and make a post request from my android app, "doPost" doesn't get called.  Any ideas?