# Android App and Http Requests

Tags: android, google-app-engine, http

I'm currently trying to send an http request from an android app to google-app-engine, this request should be received by the server who will use the parameters passed in the URL to add a new item to the datastore.

I wrote this code:

```
private class AsyncConnection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // creating the url
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            // opening the connection
            URLConnection connection;
            connection = url.openConnection();

            // get data about the connection
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            // connection was properly established
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream input = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                return input.toString();
            } else {
                Log.d("CONNECTION", "connection not HTTP_OK");
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("SMARTGAN", "MalformedURLException" ,e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("SMARTGAN", "IOException" ,e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SMARTGAN", "Exception" ,e);
        } finally { }

        return null;
    }
}
```

but when I try to execute it I don't see any new item in the datastore.
The URL itself and the code on the server are fine, when I tried and sent the URL using it worked. I don't see any error message of "connection not ok" message in the log.

Comment: Without answering your actual question, make sure you always, always close Streams with .close() after you are done consuming it!

Comment: start by logging the value of responseCode. It will tell you what kind of error it is, because that's what response code are for.

Comment: then, this `input.toString()` probably does not do what you would like it to. Also, post your log, just in case.

Comment: About the close() and to toString(), I wrote this code just to see if the connection works. And about the logging the responseCode, I wrote that I don't see any connection not ok message because responseCode = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK

Answer (score 0):

Mostly probably could be with `hostname`,  have tried this solution [How to make http post from android to google app engine server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992991/how-to-make-http-post-from-android-to-google-app-engine-server)

Also refer to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments